# Use function return value as argument to another function

Tags: postgresql

Have a table column with JSON string and a (defined) function (`get_jstr()`) that returns a single sting.

```
SELECT get_jstr();
<..returns some JSON string...>
```

How do i feed this output to `jsonb_path_query()` function?
Tried a few variants

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query( (SELECT get_jstr()), '$[0]');
SELECT jsonb_path_query( v, '$[0]') FROM (SELECT get_jstr()) v;
```

but none of them work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just `SELECT get_jstr()::jsonb -> 0`

Comment: nice; still learning the ropes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) :

```
jsonb_path_query ( target jsonb, path jsonpath [, vars jsonb [, silent boolean ]] ) → setof jsonb
```

The target should be *JSONB*, so either cast the returning value to *JSONB* :

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query( get_jstr()::jsonb, '$[0]');
```

Or edit your function to return *JSONB* instead of *JSON*

Comment: A bit simpler `SELECT jsonb_path_query(get_jstr()::jsonb, '$[0]');`